# is it recommended to enclose contents of json file inside square braces when we are parsing it with read_json() function of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I have a json file as below

```
{
   "fruit": "Apple",
   "size": "Large", 
   "color": "Red", 
   "grade": null, 
   "bool": true
}
```

when I tried to read this json file using read_json() function of pandas as below

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_json("example_1.json")
print(data.to_json(orient="records"))
```

I am getting an error
saying "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index",
but if I enclose the above json file in square braces as below

```
[{
   "fruit": "Apple",
   "size": "Large", 
   "color": "Red", 
   "grade": null, 
   "bool": true
}]
```

Now if I use read_json() function of pandas my pgm works fine, I wanted to know why this square braces have such an impact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all comes down to how pandas interprets broadcasting. When you have a dictionary (analogous to a json obj), you're basically saying that the keys are the column names, and the values are the values you'll input in your dataframe. However, when the value is a scalar-like object (i.e. *not* an iterable), pandas doesn't know *how many* items your column will have, [since scalars are broadcastable to any shape.](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/theory.broadcasting.html)

If you had a list of single values, then it'd be clear that each column would have just one item, and there'd be no ambiguity.

So, for example, the below should work just fine, since it's clear each column has just one value.

```
pd.DataFrame({
   "fruit": ["Apple"],
   "size": ["Large"], 
   "color": ["Red"], 
   "grade": [None], 
   "bool": [True]
})
```

The below should also work just fine, because a list of dictionaries is interpreted such that each item in the list is a row.

```
pd.DataFrame([{
   "fruit": "Apple",
   "size": "Large", 
   "color": "Red", 
   "grade": None, 
   "bool": True
}])
```

But the below wouldnt' work, since it's unclear how many items you'd have:

```
pd.DataFrame({
   "fruit": "Apple",
   "size": "Large", 
   "color": "Red", 
   "grade": None, 
   "bool": True
})
```

To remove ambiguity, you have to specify the indexes, which would outright specify the number of total items. For example:

```
pd.DataFrame({
   "fruit": "Apple",
   "size": "Large", 
   "color": "Red", 
   "grade": None, 
   "bool": True
}, index=[0])
```

---

```
  fruit   size color grade  bool
0  Apple  Large   Red  None  True
```

And

```
pd.DataFrame({
   "fruit": "Apple",
   "size": "Large", 
   "color": "Red", 
   "grade": None, 
   "bool": True
}, index=[0,1])
```

---

```
   fruit   size color grade  bool
0  Apple  Large   Red  None  True
1  Apple  Large   Red  None  True
```

The examples are made using the default constructor but the logic is the same for `read_json`.